# Как из сегодняшней даты вычесть нужную дату?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь из сегодняшней даты вычесть 21.01.23(как пример) сделал так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

A = datetime(2023, 1, 22, 5)

B = datetime.now()

print (A - B)
```

В результате но показывает мне минуты, секунды. Как сделать так чтоб он показывал мне только год, месяц, день, час?

Хочу чтоб он просто перестал показывать секунды при ответе, как это сделать?

Comment: Вероятно, подойдёт  dateutils.relativedelta, но вообще `год, месяц, день, час` в единственном числе настораживает

Comment: А что он должен был показать? 0 год, 0 месяц, и т.п.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь действительно идет про "чтоб он просто перестал **показывать** секунды при ответе" то вот так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
A = datetime(2023, 1, 22, 5)
B = datetime.now()
print(str(A - B).split(".")[0])
```

Результат:

```
5 days, 17:18:37
```

По ходу хочу заметить, что timedelta с годами не работает в принципе. И с месяцами, кстати, тоже.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так же заметил что если "." Поменять на ":", то он будет показывать только часы, то что надо:)

Answer (score 0):

timedelta выше дня не показывает, можно просто возвращать кол-во дней и минут

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

A = datetime(2023, 1, 22, 5)

B = datetime.now()
R = A - B
print(R.days, R.minutes)
```

Comment: Надо так чтоб в конечном итоге получилось(пример): 16.01.23 13:00 - 21.01.23 05:00 = - 5 дней, 16:00... Он считает так же, но надо чтоб не показывал секунды и долесекунды